# Solve this integral

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve this integral from so many days, but not able to do this. Can anyone solve this integral : $$\int{\frac{1}{N^3\Bigg[N+\delta\Bigg(1+\frac{A}{\kappa-\frac{3}{2}}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{N^2}\bigg) \Bigg)^{-\kappa+\frac{1}{2}}\Bigg]}}dN$$, where $$A, \delta, \kappa$$ are arbitrary constants. I urgently need this for my project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can give us an idea of what you tried?

Comment: I tried it by substitution method.

Comment: Who said there must be a way?

Comment: This case $\kappa= 1/3$ is apparently not elementary $$\int \!{\frac {1}{{n}^{3}} \left( n+1-6\,\sqrt [6]{1-{n}^{-2}}
 \right) ^{-1}}\,{\rm d}n$$